# How to get photos of a facebook album in iPhone SDK not working

Tags: xcode, facebook

*Currently, my plan is to query for a user’s albums, and then iterate through those albums and get all the images. Is there a good way of skipping the albums step entirely? Here is the code I am using to get > their album info: - I want to get list of photo albums. I used the > following code but no luck.

```
     -(IBAction)updateStatus:(id)sender {
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {


    [self promptUserWithAccountNameForStatusUpdate];


} else {


    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_stream",@"user_photos",
                            nil];
    [self controlStatusUsable:NO];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, 
                                                  FBSessionState status, 
                                                  NSError *error) {
                                  // if login fails for any reason, we alert
                                  if (error) {


                                  } else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status)) {

                                      [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
                                       ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, 


         NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                                           if (!error) {

 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/albums"                                                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                 if (!error) {

         NSString *urlstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=%@&fields=id,picture,name,birthday",[[FBSession activeSession]accessTokenData]];
                                      NSLog(@"the tkens:%@",urlstr);
                                                                             int j=0;









                        NSLog(@"Results: %@", result);

                         NSString *fbAccessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];  
                         //NSLog(@"get access:%@",fbAccessToken);

                                                                         }
                                                                     }
                                                ];



                                           }
                                            [self controlStatusUsable:YES];
                                       }];                                                
                                  }
                              }];
}


  }
```

please anybody give me idea or references.